# Dependency Injection (DI) in ASP.NET Core/MVC 6 ViewModel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm successfully using ASP.NET 5/MVC 6 DI in my controllers using Constructor Injection.

I now have a scenario where I want my View Models to utalise a service in the Validate method when implementing the IValidatableObject.

Constructor injection in the ViewModel does not work because they need a default parameterless constructor. Validation Context.GetService does not work either.

```
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        MyService myService = (MyService)validationContext.GetService(typeof(MyService));
```

always results in MyService being null.

ASP.NET 4, I would create ValidatableObjectAdapter, register it via  DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterDefaultValidatableObjectAdapterFactory & then I could use the validationContext to object references to services.

I'm currently using the build in DI container for ASP.NET 5, will move to structuremap at some stage) not that this should matter.

My specific validation is that an object's property (eg, user name) is unique. I want to delegate this test to the service layer.

Comment: A ViewModel should not contain business logic. In this case, you should have a ValidatorProcessor, and there's no reason you can't use constructor injection.

Comment: I'm not suggesting the viewModel would have business logic.  The pattern would either be If (myService.IsDuplicate(Name)) {yieldReturn  new validationResult, or return myService.ValidateCanCreate(Name, Type, SomeOtherProperty) - anyway, what is a ValidatorProcessor?  I can't seem to find any relevant references for them.

Comment: You said "constructor injection in the View Model". I don't understand why you need to do that, and I don't understand why you couldn't do constructor injection there if you have a valid reason to be doing it.

Comment: @mason - see the last sentence - an objects name needs to be unique.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that sentence either. Please explain what you mean.

Comment: Simple example:  Screen to enter a user. The name property of the user needs to be unique across all other users in the system.  This requires a database lookup, ie, a call to the repository layer either directly or via the service layer (depending on your architecture/structure)

Comment: What is a ValidatorProcessor?  How does that model work? Google does not show anything relivent

Comment: But that has nothing to do with the problem at hand, and does not change anything about your incorrect statements that view models can't have an empty constructor. And it doesn't explain why you're trying to put business logic in a view model.

Comment: It would just be a class (not a view model!) that would run your validation logic.

Comment: @mason how does that class hook into the MVC framework? How does it get called? How does it add errors to model state and invalidate model state? How does it get DI?  Do you have anything more to add then "just create a class and don't put any business logic in a view model" - One could argue that [Required], [MaxLength], etc attributes are business logic in the view model.  I'm not really interested in those arguments, only how to get dependencies into an implementation of IValidatableObject's validate method in a view model. - IValidatableObject is fully supported in MVC so can't be that bad

Comment: Show how you registered your dependencies.

Comment: Use the [FromServices] attribute on a view model property to use property injection during model binding. http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2016/02/18/avoiding-the-service-locator-pattern-in-asp-net-core.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of ASP.NET RC2, [FromServices] has been removed.

If you want DI in your viewModels purely for IValidatableObject.Validate then you can use validationContext.GetService(type) to get your service. This did not work in RC1

EG

```
MyService myService = (MyService)validationContext.GetService(typeof(myService));
```

Here is a generic extension method to make that a little more pleasant to deal with.

```
public static class ValidationContextExtensions
{
    public static T GetService<T>(this ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        return (T)validationContext.GetService(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is now the correct answer with ASP.Net Core 1. Also great work with the extension method.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to  @odeToCode for the answer. For the sake of completeness I re-post his comment as the answer with my (working) example. The magic is the [FromServices] attribute.

```
public class CreateDynamicMappingProfileViewModel : IValidatableObject
{

    [Display(Name = "Name", Order = 1), Required, MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The name field allows a maximum of 50 characters")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Data Format", Order = 2), Required]
    public DataFormat DataFormat { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Data Context", Order = 3), Required]
    public DataContextType DataContextType { get; set; }

    [FromServices]
    public IMappingProfileServices MappingProfileServices { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        IMappingProfile mappingProfile = new DynamicMappingProfile(Name, DataFormat, DataContextType);
        return MappingProfileServices.ValidateCanSave(mappingProfile);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wonderful attribute, thanks for an answer, I wanted to post mine but found yours. :) Greetings.

Comment: `FromServices` does not exist anymore in latest ASP.NET Core 1.0

Comment: Note that [FromServices] still exists at least according to the latest MVC core docs (but not for properties) - see https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection.html#action-injection-with-fromservices