# How to correctly localize validation in IValidatableObject.Validate method for ASP.Net Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a model implementing IValidatableObject and I need to localize ValidationResults, how can I correctly achieve that ?

Currently I came up with an IValidatableObject.Validate method that looks as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    var stringLocalizer = validationContext.GetService(typeof(IStringLocalizer<MyModel>)) as IStringLocalizer<MyModel>;

    //Validation logic implementation...

    yield return new ValidationResult(stringLocalizer["This thing is the error message"]);
}
```

What I'm doing here is locating an IStringLocalizer instance by using the ValidationContext.GetService method.

This approach works but my main problem is that I'm not entirely sure that this is correct especially because I need to rely on a service locator to get the IStringLocalizer

Comment: I’m a bit confused with all the versioning and what not…but you might be able to inject a service inside your ViewModel using the [FromServices] attribute. But you should double check to make sure that attribute has not been removed (or brought back). This post could help clarify http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35518476/dependency-injection-di-in-asp-net-core-mvc-6-viewmodel

Comment: @Vlince Sadly by looking at the documentation the FromServices attribute is usable only on parameters, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromservicesattribute